# Zeppelin Remote endpoint 'localhost:47811' is not accessible (might be initializing)

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I want to deploy a zeppelin notebook in my mesos cluster where I have installed the Spark Cluster. The thing is that I achieve to deploy the spark script (I see the driver Id) but nothing happens, it is in running mode but nothing executing.

If I see the zeppelin logs I have this entry repeteadly:

```
 Remote endpoint 'localhost:47811' is not accessible (might be initializing)
```

And at the end it gives an error:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException:      org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

But the spark driver is still running...

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I've achieved to launch a remote interpreter (the Spark Mesos framework one) but when I launch a notebook nothings happen and never ends. I can see the Spark driver and the Spark UI but nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after hours of investigation I achieved to configure Zeppelin in my Mesos cluster. The fault was that I had a MASTER environment variable set im my Spark distribution. After removed and following the documentation of Zeppelin everything worked!

thanks.